# Read a data from an input Stream line by line in Smalltalk

Tags: stream, smalltalk

Is there a way to read from an input line, line by line in Smalltalk?
I found one approach, which is to use "upTo: Character cr."
Is there any other approach?
Or can I read the line as a String?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how

```
string := 'line one
line two
line three'.
stream := string readStream
```

Now,

```
stream nextLine "answers with 'line one'".
stream nextLine "answers with 'line two'".
stream nextLine "answers with 'line three'"
```

and at this point

```
stream atEnd "answers with true"
```

Notice that `nextLine` consumes the end-of-line without including it in the answer. If the last line doesn't have an end-of-line, then `nextLine` will stop right at the end.

Notice also that this allows for a loop to read lines while the `stream` has more data

```
[stream atEnd] whileFalse: [self doSomethingWith: stream nextLine]
```

If you want to read again from the beginning:

```
stream reset
```

and if you want to get back to a previos position:

```
stream position: pos
```

for example

```
stream nextLine "read first line".
pos2 := stream position "position of the second line".
stream nextLine "read second line".
stream nextLine "read third line".
stream position: pos2 "get back to line 2".
stream nextLine "again, line 2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What I'm trying to do is read the data entered in a text editor (name: ops) and inserting each line in an OrderedCollection.
val:= (ops value) readStream.
[val atEnd] whileFalse:
[aCollection add: val nextLine]. 
But i get an ReadStream does not understand error. any suggestions?

Comment: What dialect are you using? What's the class of your text editor?

Comment: I'm using the cincom IDE.I'm obtaining the value from the GUI text editor. I just checked the type of value retrieved from the text editor using (ops value class)- which is Text. Is their a way I can convert  a Text object to a String?

Comment: Try sending the message `string` to the `Text` object. Or browse the class `Text` and find a message that would answer with it.